# jquery function doesn't work after removing display:none;

Tags: jquery

```
 $('.smileys img').click(function () {
            alert("hello");

        });


<div class="smileys">
<img src="images/smileys/mad.gif"/>
</div>
```

.smileys css is display:none;

A button reveals the smileys using this: $(".smileys").css('display', 'block');

Now, after making .smileys visible the first function does not work. But when the smileys are visible by default it does work.

Comment: When you bind the event, those elements don't exist in the DOM, which means the selector is empty, which means no event is actually bound.

Comment: Have you tried using the `.on` method? $(".smileys img").on("click", function() {});

Comment: @zzzzBov I understand that but I don't know what to do to fix this.

Comment: @ArnelleBalane Just did, makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need event delegation -

```
$(document).on('click','.smileys img',function () {
            alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `.on('click', function() {....`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.on()` method:

```
$('.smileys img').on("click", function () {
  // code 
});
```

Or the `.delegate()` method:

```
$("body").delegate(".smileys img", "click", function() {
  // code
});
```

Also, for revealing the smileys you can use the `.show()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the event handler to an element that exists in the DOM at the time of the binding.

If you're calling your script as:

```
<script>
    $('.smileys img').click(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
</script>
<div class="smileys">
    <img src="images/smileys/mad.gif"/>
</div>
```

Then you'll need to delegate the event to something that exists, such as `window`, `document`, or `body`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.smileys img', function () {...});
```

Alternatively you can wait until the document is ready before binding the events:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) { //aliasing shortcut for $(document).ready...
        $('.smileys img').click(function () {
            alert("hello");
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="smileys">
    <img src="images/smileys/mad.gif"/>
</div>
```

Document.ready causes the function to be executed after all of the content of the page has been built, but before images and other external content has finished loading.

Alternatively you can simply place the `<script>` *after* the elements are created in the DOM:

```
<div class="smileys">
    <img src="images/smileys/mad.gif"/>
</div>
<script>
    $('.smileys img').click(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```